# Will Apple's Mac Remote Wipe delete items on external disk?

Tags: mac, time-machine, backup, find-my-mac

With all the news about remote wipe I am wondering if having a backup on an external disk that is connected to my Mac is OK.  Or if someone did a remote wipe, would they wipe that disk as well?

Comment: To find out, I guess somebody with a good backup and some spare time would need to volunteer.

Answer (score 3):

If Apple's incredibly vague description of "your Mac" and "the disk" also includes what is attached to it, which anyone might assume — then **YES**. On the other hand, if fluff marketing jargon and disappearing statements might leave some doubts in your mind, I would say **NO**. The only way to really know is to do what myhd suggests.

---

Taken from a cached page published by Apple on Jul 15, 2012 21:25:58 GMT:

> **Instant wipe**
>
> With FileVault 2, instant wipe removes the encryption key from your
>   Mac instantaneously, making the data completely inaccessible. Then
>   your Mac performs an entire wipe of the data from the disk. External
>   drive support
>
> **FileVault 2** supports encryption of external USB and FireWire drives.

Source: [Apple - OS X Lion - Over 250 new features. Read about all of them.](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aIwhd7C8QHNYJ%3aimages.apple.com/hk/en/macosx/whats-new/features.html%20&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a)

Visiting the same (live) page now displays:

> **FileVault 2 encrypts your data.**
>
> With FileVault 2, your data is safe and secure — even if it falls into
>   the wrong hands. FileVault 2 encrypts the entire drive on your Mac,
>   protecting your data with XTS-AES 128 encryption. Initial encryption
>   is fast and unobtrusive. It can also encrypt any removable drive,
>   helping you secure Time Machine backups or other external drives with
>   ease. Want to start fresh or give your Mac to someone else? FileVault
>   2 makes it easy to clean data off your Mac. Instant wipe removes the
>   encryption key from your Mac — making the data completely inaccessible
>   — then proceeds with a thorough wipe of all data from the disk.
>
> **OS X and iCloud can help find your missing Mac.**
>
> OS X and iCloud can help keep your Mac safe even when you misplace it.
>   Sign in to iCloud.com from another computer or use the Find My iPhone
>   app on an iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch to locate your missing Mac on a
>   map. If your Mac is offline when you try to find it, you can ask to
>   receive an email as soon as it makes a Wi-Fi connection. You can also
>   display a message on your Mac screen so whoever has it knows how to
>   get it back to you. And until your Mac is back in safe hands, you can
>   set a passcode lock remotely, or even initiate a remote wipe to delete
>   your personal data and restore your Mac to its factory settings.

---